# GCP deployment port issue for a node js project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have deployed one node js project in which a http server is created at port 8080 and listening at 8080 and a service url is generated.But inside http.createServer i am creating another server for a nlp engine which is listening at port 8081.So using the service url generated after deployment i am able to hit server running at 8080,but how to access the nlp engine server running at 8081 using the same service url with out using router?ordo gcp doesnt allow creation of two server listening at two ports with the same service url?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try http://hostname:8081? what does it say? 
If the port 8081 is open, then ideally you should be able to access that NPL engine, else you may need to get the port open in GCP.